# Magento 2.4.1 Checkout Error - Current Customer Does Not Have An Active Cart

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, error, magento2.4.1

I have a weird issue here...

When the user tries to complete their order, they get the error seen below. However, the order completes. There's nothing alarming in the logs either. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you

[image: error]

Answer (score 2):

This issue comes from file:
`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/model/cart/estimate-service.js`

```
estimateTotalsShipping = function () {
    totalsDefaultProvider.estimateTotals(quote.shippingAddress());
},
```

You can try to modify it in your theme or using mixing to something like this:

```
estimateTotalsShipping = function () {
    let cart = customerData.get('cart')();
    if (!cart || !cart.items || !cart.items.length) {
        return;
    }

    totalsDefaultProvider.estimateTotals(quote.shippingAddress());
},
```

**I hope it will help**

Answer (score 1):

I too faced the same issue in my local. I rectified the issue by disabling the SMTP extension which I have added to send the mail in another custom module.

Comment: Thanks, After disabled the SMTP Extension it's working now

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using athlete 2 theme and probably with Stripe payment. This problem is related to theme. Please submit support request at developer.